# How to Show 2 Gradients at Once?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make 2 gradients overlap each other at the same time with this code...

```
    #grad1 {
       height: 3px;
       background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
       background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
       background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
       background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
    }
    #grad2 {
        height: 3px;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2184E2 , #AE1937);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #2184E2, #AE1937);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #2184E2, #AE1937);
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #2184E2 , #AE1937);
    }
```

But it doesn't overlap each other like I want it to.

How can I make #grad1 overlap #grad2 so they're both visible at the same time?

Comment: I'd imagine you need two components, one with each gradient. Applying both to the same component will only apply the last (depending on browser weirdness).

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```css
#grad1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#grad2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

This way it just overlaps both the stuff, keeping the `#grad2` on top of `#grad1`. Make sure, you have another `<div>`, which is the parent of both having a `position: relative` to it.

**Snippet**

```css
#grad1 {
  height: 3px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
}
#grad2 {
  height: 3px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2184E2 , #AE1937);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #2184E2, #AE1937);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #2184E2, #AE1937);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2184E2 , #AE1937);
}

#grad1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#grad2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.parent {position: relative; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
.parent > div {width: 50px;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="grad1"></div>
  <div id="grad2"></div>
</div>
```